# connection to rabbitmq server seems to never hapen

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I implemented a basic communication using Rabbitmq in c#. I created two queues and listen to one of them. But when i check with the rabbitmq web client i can see that queues are created but there is no connections. When i do the same with python it works.

The programm is wainting to consume, whereas there is a mesage in the listened queue (i can see on the web client). The same with channels, with python code the channel is created but not with c# code.

I don't undersatnd what i missed

```cs
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost"};
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
   channel.QueueDeclare(queue:"state-reward", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
   channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "action", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

   var state = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
   state.Received += (model, ea) =>
   { 
       #mycode
   }
   channel.BasicConsume(queue:"state-reward", autoAck: true, consumer: state);
}
```

Whereas there is a message in queue "state-reward", the program does not read it. it is waiting...

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You are disposing the connection and channel right away, thus closing the connection/channel.

Register your connection as a singleton and inject it since its meant to be long lived. You can do the same with your channel (or create it in your ctor).
Then remove the using statements.

You can then implement IDisposable and close the connection/channel in the Dispose method. You should register `MyConsumer` as a singleton as well since you don't want to create a new channel/declare the queues more than one time.

Something like this:

```
public class MyConsumer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IModel _channel;

    public MyConsumer(IConnection connection)
    {
        _channel = connection.CreateModel();
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue:"state-reward", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "action", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        var state = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        state.Received += (model, ea) =>
        { 
            // Do something here
        }
        _channel.BasicConsume(queue:"state-reward", autoAck: true, consumer: state);
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
        _connection?.Abort();
        _connection?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you don't use DI for some reason, just remove the using statements in your code and it should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ automatically disposes any channel which might be open on a connection , if the underlying connection is disposed. Similarly if the underlying channel is closed or disposed the Consumer is closed as well , essentially the event handler stops getting notifications from the RabbitMQ Server.

In your case as soon as the using block goes out of scope first the channel is disposed and then as the connection block goes out of scope the connection is disposed.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost"};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
var channel = connection.CreateModel();

   channel.QueueDeclare(queue:"state-reward", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
   channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "action", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

   var state = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
   state.Received += (model, ea) =>
   { 
       #mycode
   }
   channel.BasicConsume(queue:"state-reward", autoAck: true, consumer: state);
```

Obviously you need to manage the channels and connections, as recommended. See  [this CloudAMQ blog post on common mistakes](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-19-part4-rabbitmq-13-common-errors.html), by Lovina Johansson:

> 2. **Don’t use too many connections or channels.**
>
>    Try to keep the connection/channel count low. Use separate connections to publish and consume. Ideally, you should have one connection per process, and then use one channel per thread in your application.
>
>    - Reuse connections
>    - 1 connection for publishing
>    - 1 connection for consuming